# Displaying a queue using for loop in Java

Tags: java, queue

I am displaying the contents of my implementation of a queue in Java. While the wrap around works (the size of the queue is 3), I'm having trouble displaying the queue when the front of the queue is greater than the rear.

Here is the code I'm using to display:

```
     System.out.println("front");
     System.out.println("=====");
     if(front < rear ) {
         for(int i = front; i != rear; i++ ) {
              System.out.println(i +":> " + queue[i]);
         }
     }
     else {
         for(int i = front; i != rear; i= (i + 1) % SIZE ) {
              System.out.println(i +":> " + queue[i]);
         }
     }

     System.out.println("=====");
```

For example, let's say that front is 1, rear is 0 and `SIZE = 3`.
My code prints out the contents of `queue[1]`, `queue[2]` in that order.

Why does it terminate when `i == 2`? Shouldn't `i= (i + 1) % SIZE` change the value of `i` to 0 and thus make it equal to rear and *then* print out the value of `queue[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i == rear, your loop won't execute, because the i != rear is false. 
If you want to loop around, do something like:

```
int i = front;
do{
    System.out.println(i +":> " + queue[i]);
    i=(i+1)%Size;
}while(i != front)
```

Comment: The circular buffer may no be full, in that case using while(!=front) as check will lead to the access of illegal element.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `SIZE = 3` and `rear <= front`, so let's say `rear = 0`, `front = 2`, then the execution of your for loop does something like:

1. Set `i = 2`
2. Execute body
3. Set `i = (2+1) % 3 = 0`
4. Check `i != rear`, or `0 != 0`, this is false, terminate loop.

Assuming this is a circular buffer, I'd iterate it like this:

```
int i = front;
do{
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
    if(i >= SIZE){
        i = 0;
    }
}while(i != (rear+1) % SIZE);
```

Comment: i==1, rear==0, the loop won't proceed with the condition check you provide.

Comment: I see, thanks. I've never used the != condition in a for loop before.

Comment: ：'i-1!=rear' may not work either. Consider the initial condition given by the problem, where i==front==1 and rear==0...

Comment: @RollingBoy: quite right, my first condition was correct for a different structure.

Answer (score 0):

when i==2, it will become 0 at the end of the current iteration.
Then i==0, rear==0, i==rear, the loop terminates.

EDIT: This works but it doesn't look elegant

```
 int i = front;
 for(; i != rear; i= (i + 1) % SIZE ) {
          System.out.println(i +":> " + queue[i]);
 }
 System.out.println(i +":> " + queue[i]);
```

Comment: I just realized that it wasn't the for loop, it was the code for setting the front and the rear. They should always be 1 ahead of the location in the array, so if it was stored in [0] front should be [1]. Essentially I was asking the wrong question, sorry!

Comment: Actually, scratch that. When the Queue is full you would have to go through the whole loop. Your code helped! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is homework, why not use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html ?

Comment: Ok no problem, just maybe next time please specify it in the request :-)